# Trying to upload .zip file to Application Loader and I get "No .app bundles found in package"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working in Swift and Xcode 6 beta 5.
I'm new to the whole process of publishing apps to the app store and I don't really understand this- what is the .app file? The file I have been working in is .xcodeproj.

I just zipped up the whole folder (with the tests and .xcodeproj file) and selected it in the Application Loader because I need to submit my binary, and I got the error "No .app bundles found in package". What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to upload an app developed in Xcode 6 until it is officially released. And zipping is not part of the upload process.

Have a look at the Ready Today section at https://developer.apple.com/swift/

The .app is the package that contains all the resources that your app will need. When you come to publish it, you will create an archive on the Xcode Product menu, and then to validate and upload, go to Window -> Organizer and select Archives on the top bar. Here you are shown your archives and can validate to make sure it's all code signed etc, and submit them.